# How to return null results after mv-apply on JSON array?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have this query

**Query 1**

```
AuditLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(30d)
| where OperationName == "Add application"
| mv-expand TargetResources
| project AppName = tostring(TargetResources.displayName), TargetResources.modifiedProperties, AppId = parse_json(tostring(TargetResources.modifiedProperties[0].newValue))[0]
```

**Query 1 results**

| AppName | TargetResources_modifiedProperties | AppId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| App1 | [ { "displayName": "AppId", "oldValue": "[]", "newValue": "["a2042ae7-b086-4738-ac37-80d7a49f270f"]" }, { "displayName": "DisplayName", "oldValue": "[]", "newValue": "["App1"]" } ] | a2042ae7-b086-4738-ac37-80d7a49f270f |
| App2 | [ { "displayName": "AppName", "oldValue": null, "newValue": ""App2"" }, { "displayName": "BackendAppTimeout", "oldValue": null, "newValue": ""Default"" }, { "displayName": "UseHTTPOnlyCookie", "oldValue": null, "newValue": ""False"" } ] |  |

You can see that **App2** doesn't contain the object where displayName = AppId in the **TargetResources_modifiedProperties** column, and so **AppId** column is null.

Due to the **AppId** value not always being the `[0]` index of **TargetResources.modifiedProperties**, I've edited my query a bit like so

**Query 2**

```
AuditLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(30d)
| where OperationName == "Add application"
| mv-expand TargetResources
| project AppName = tostring(TargetResources.displayName), AppId = TargetResources.modifiedProperties
| mv-apply AppId on (
    where AppId.displayName == "AppId"
    | project AppId = parse_json(tostring(AppId.newValue))[0]
)
```

**Query 2 results**

| AppName | TargetResources_modifiedProperties | AppId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| App1 | [ { "displayName": "AppId", "oldValue": "[]", "newValue": "["a2042ae7-b086-4738-ac37-80d7a49f270f"]" }, { "displayName": "DisplayName", "oldValue": "[]", "newValue": "["App1"]" } ] | a2042ae7-b086-4738-ac37-80d7a49f270f |

However, with the updated query, the entire **App2** row is no longer displayed, I guess due to the **AppId** property being null.

How can I still retain the **App2** row in the results?

**Sample**

```
print AppName = "App1", TargetResources_modifiedProperties = dynamic([ { "displayName": "AppId", "oldValue": "[]", "newValue": "[\"a2042ae7-b086-4738-ac37-80d7a49f270f\"]" }, { "displayName": "DisplayName", "oldValue": "[]", "newValue": "[\"App1\"]" } ]) , AppId = "a2042ae7-b086-4738-ac37-80d7a49f270f"
| union (
    print AppName = "App2", TargetResources_modifiedProperties = dynamic([ { "displayName": "AppName", "oldValue": null, "newValue": "\"App2\"" }, { "displayName": "BackendAppTimeout", "oldValue": null, "newValue": "\"Default\"" }, { "displayName": "UseHTTPOnlyCookie", "oldValue": null, "newValue": "\"False\"" } ]) , AppId = ""
)
```

Comment: When asking a data related question, please provide a sample data (raw data, not the result of your attempts) + required result (in tabular format).

Comment: You still didn't add the required results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatable(AppName:string, TargetResources_modifiedProperties:dynamic, AppId:string)
[
    "App1", dynamic([ { "displayName": "AppId", "oldValue": "[]", "newValue": "[\"a2042ae7-b086-4738-ac37-80d7a49f270f\"]" }, { "displayName": "DisplayName", "oldValue": "[]", "newValue": "[\"App1\"]" } ]) ,"a2042ae7-b086-4738-ac37-80d7a49f270f"
   ,"App2", dynamic([ { "displayName": "AppName", "oldValue": null, "newValue": "\"App2\"" }, { "displayName": "BackendAppTimeout", "oldValue": null, "newValue": "\"Default\"" }, { "displayName": "UseHTTPOnlyCookie", "oldValue": null, "newValue": "\"False\"" } ]) ,""
]
| mv-apply TR_mP = TargetResources_modifiedProperties on 
  (
    summarize AppId = parse_json(tostring(take_anyif(TR_mP.newValue, TR_mP.displayName == "AppId")))[0]
  )
```

| AppName | TargetResources_modifiedProperties | AppId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| App1 | [{"displayName":"AppId","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"a2042ae7-b086-4738-ac37-80d7a49f270f\"]"},{"displayName":"DisplayName","oldValue":"[]","newValue":"[\"App1\"]"}] | a2042ae7-b086-4738-ac37-80d7a49f270f |
| App2 | [{"displayName":"AppName","oldValue":null,"newValue":"\"App2\""},{"displayName":"BackendAppTimeout","oldValue":null,"newValue":"\"Default\""},{"displayName":"UseHTTPOnlyCookie","oldValue":null,"newValue":"\"False\""}] |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA41STWuDQBS8B/Iflj0paLAm1DSQQ9tQmksbiu3FiLy4z7DNuiuuttiP/14/EhpKQnVPDvNm5j2GQVG/jUDjOsseIMWZLnIutxbxId9i8YRalXmMOkoV4wlHtspVhnnBUc9YJSHlsUXq2SXbT5rDQTAckPqjNXxBLbKnGQH5JJRxnQmoGis6aylLVnOoEuwFRNmCQdggEt9/kTUF15m4gJ69caaX9sQbT22Ix549dZgHk6vE9ZxkTUNKvq0TPouj3z5uTfROjYQmsXq503Ztq5l1/1/7RBRZCvEnSpvEXdMza91AvEPJao7PU1Rl0UdxgQmUojgr%20qzx3vdXj1JUt0rteK%20YdyA0tpLdwepjhMPBF0nfbMgyURH/KUpXZN6jV0RJ0pzS6GqkyzSFnH9gV7NaIoNcY/SqlTQK1bXOKGCHEciKJ0brNDrEszrn0dGSZD4/NM80zcAJGyPzByTTD5wLAwAA)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not actually seeing any difference in the results with what you've provided here and what I used. I updated with the data sample as well