# KQL/ADX - mv-apply on empty array removes records

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I would like to extract values from a dynamic field with JSON content and find the smallest value based on a calculation during streaming ingestion. The array may also be empty.

I tried the following:

```
datatable (Id:int, BatteryDetails: dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic([]),
    2, dynamic([{"fullChargedCapacity": 5, "designedCapacity": 10}]) 
]
| mv-apply f = BatteryDetails on
    (
        project LowestBatteryLevel = toint(round(todouble(f.fullChargedCapacity) / todouble(f.designedCapacity) * 100))
        | top 1 by LowestBatteryLevel asc
    )
| project Id, LowestBatteryLevel
```

Result:

| Id | LowestBatteryLevel |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 50 |

I would like to get:

| Id | LowestBatteryLevel |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 50 |

Any idea how the record 1 can be retained? Already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74365147/how-to-return-null-results-after-mv-apply-on-json-array) but this did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:**

```
datatable (Id:int, BatteryDetails: dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic([]),
    2, dynamic([{"fullChargedCapacity": 5, "designedCapacity": 10}]) 
]
| mv-apply f = BatteryDetails on
    (
        summarize  LowestBatteryLevel = min(toint(round(todouble(f.fullChargedCapacity) / todouble(f.designedCapacity) * 100)))        
    )
| project Id, LowestBatteryLevel
```

I referred the same [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74365147/how-to-return-null-results-after-mv-apply-on-json-array) that you shared and wrote the above query. The query uses the `mv-apply` operator to apply the `summarize`  to each element of the `BatteryDetails` dynamic field. The `summarize` operator calculates the `LowestBatteryLevel` by dividing the `fullChargedCapacity` by the `designedCapacity`, multiplying by 100, rounding to the nearest integer, and converting to an integer. The `min` function is used to select min value in each group.

**Output:**

| Id | LowestBatteryLevel |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 50 |

['fiddle'](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WQy2rDMBBF9/6KwStNUduk0C4M3TTdBPIHwYuJNU5V9DDyOMFp++9VTJ8hGcEgruYyR9eQ5LNxDGppKhtEwxOJcBqfWci6vgIzBvK2wWJdQK65/lbUukY9aXe/2s/bW9kOzi1eKG3ZLKijxspYVvCgoTTc2234J89nHxouee4vempEKOriHfzumrrOjdDC48kXIIaJUk39WP3gPSV7YIBV3HMvX4YV79hlv7dBScxpqBSHYPLdxCGHpNqbM4AIt/Bn4hQU4SqTzhBx2o8ZtkvxlRuBpdFnAD4BHGaM/ZQBAAA=)

Comment: This does not return the lowest battery level, e.g. if you set the 2nd record to "2, dynamic([{"fullChargedCapacity": 5, "designedCapacity": 10}, {"fullChargedCapacity": 4, "designedCapacity": 10}])". It will just return a random one.

Comment: Replaced `take_any()` with `min()` function. Thus will take the lowest battery level.

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable (Id:int, BatteryDetails: dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic([]),
    2, dynamic([{"fullChargedCapacity": 5, "designedCapacity": 10}]) 
]
| extend LowestBatteryLevel = iff(isnull(BatteryDetails) or isempty(BatteryDetails), null,
                                mv-apply f = BatteryDetails on
                                (
                                    project LowestBatteryLevel = toint(round(todouble(f.fullChargedCapacity) / todouble(f.designedCapacity) * 100))
                                    | top 1 by LowestBatteryLevel asc
                                ))
| project Id, LowestBatteryLevel
```

Comment: This does not work. The "null" is not accepted and even when changing to 0, the expression around mv-apply throws syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a possible solution by faking a dummy entry in case the array is empty:

```
datatable (Id:int, BatteryDetails: dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic([]),
    2, dynamic([{"fullChargedCapacity": 5, "designedCapacity": 10}]) 
]
| extend BatteryDetailsTmp = iff(array_length(BatteryDetails) == 0, dynamic([{"fullChargedCapacity": 0, "designedCapacity": 1}]), BatteryDetails)
| mv-apply f = BatteryDetailsTmp on
    (
        project LowestBatteryLevel = toint(round(todouble(f.fullChargedCapacity) / todouble(f.designedCapacity) * 100))
        | top 1 by LowestBatteryLevel asc
    )
| project-away BatteryDetailsTmp
| project Id, LowestBatteryLevel
```